# How to fire an event when meta content changes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, meta

I have a web app that runs inside of a viewer. The viewer responsibility is to update the content value of some meta tags.

If there a way to use javascript or the jQuery library to setup a call back every time the content of the meta changes?

Assuming I have the following meta tag

```
<meta name="some_name" content="">
```

I tried something like the following

```
$('meta[name="some_name"]').change(function(e){

    alert( $(this).attr('value') );

});
```

But that does not work when the meta content changes.

How can I fire an event when the meta content change?

Comment: Wait, what meta tags are changing, and why? That sounds really bizarre.

Comment: The viewer communicates with a phone system. When a phone call is assigned to the user the phone system updates the some values in some meta tags that I like to change on the screen when their value change

Comment: Where is the code that does the update? There are no events you can bind to ... `change` is for form controls. There are MutationObservers but they don't have full cross browser support. The best bet is to tap into the actual code that does the update